# Apache redirect loop with mod_alias (mod_rewrite not available)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there any way to forward all requests to `app.phar/$1` when `mod_rewrite` is not available for apache? The following is causing a redirect loop:

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/(.*)$ /app.phar/$1
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would cause a loop because `(.*)` catches `/app.phar/...`, and will therefore redirect again.

You should still have [`mod_dir`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html) available, and so you can try with the following instead:

```bash
FallbackResource /app.phar
```

For more about this directive, please view the [current documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource).